# Quick fixes for Scala in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, import

I have the following code:

```
    var i = sqrt (30)
```

To use the sqrt function in Scala I have to import `scala.math.sqrt`
I am using IntelliJ and I am new in it and Scala. In Eclipse when programming java, when I use a function where the package is not imported in the source, Eclipse recommends the package and I can insert it by a simple mouse click.
Is something similar possible in IntelliJ when programming Scala?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, Intellij supports this kind of feature. Usually when an import is available, you can just press Alt+Enter and it will be autocompleted.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/auto-import.html

With that specific class it may fail for some reason, this system is not perfect, but when there are no implicits or ambiguity, it should work really well.